# I am stuck unable to understand this code Can anyone please eloborate me

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Function GenerateHeader(ByVal FrameNumber As String) As String
    Dim HeaderRecord As String = FrameNumber
      Try
          For Each P As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In Me.GetType().GetProperties()
               If P.CanRead Then
                   If P.GetValue( Me, Nothing)Is Nothing Then 'get value of me.
                         HeaderRecord += "|"
                        Else
                            HeaderRecord += P.GetValue(Me, Nothing).ToString & "|"
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                Return HeaderRecord
            Catch ex As Exception
                LogError("ASTMHeader", "GenerateHeader", Err.Erl, Err.Description, "")
                Return HeaderRecord
            End Try
        End Function
```

Comment: I would recommend you step through it and see what it does. It is hard to say much from the provided code - don't really know what Me is (it is a reference to a class object, i.e., like "this" in Javascript or "self" in Python) but we have no idea what kind of object this is - maybe a form class? Maybe something else? Apparently the passed in argument is useless though - never used. Do you have any guess as to what kind of "header" this generates?

Comment: @topsail The passed in argument is being used.  It's set to HeaderRecord and then potentially text is added to it and then returned.

Comment: Read the docs here, especially the example code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-6.0 Understand this method, and you should be able to infer what the method does.

Comment: One thing the code is doing is ignoring the exception object `ex` and using the legacy `Err` object. Looks like this code was ported from VB6 to VB.NET. It is also silently logging the error, but returning a value from the Function, so the consumer would have no idea that an exception occurred, and the calling code would go on as nothing wrong happened.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad piece of code. I'm not sure where you got it, but it needs re-writing.

I have added comments to the code for you, but basically this code uses reflection to get all of the properties of the class the function is embedded into. It then uses reflection to try to read the values of each of those properties for the current object, and returns them as a pipe separated string. If I had to guess, someone is trying to store the values to a database or file and restore them at a later date. This is bad way of doing things though. Usually you would serialize and deserialize an object to and from JSON or XML to achieve this.

```
Public Function GenerateHeader(ByVal FrameNumber As String) As String
    Dim HeaderRecord As String = FrameNumber
    Try
        ' Use reflection to get all of the properties on the class this function is a part of 
        ' Loop them
        For Each P As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In Me.GetType().GetProperties()
            ' Check to see if this is a readable property 
            If P.CanRead Then
                ' P.GetValue(obj As Object, index As Object())
                ' Is the value of the property Nothing (i.e. not set) then just add a | to the result
                If P.GetValue(Me, Nothing) Is Nothing Then 'get value of me.
                    HeaderRecord += "|"
                Else
                    ' Otherwise add the Value, coverted to a string, to the result followed by a |
                    HeaderRecord += P.GetValue(Me, Nothing).ToString & "|"
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return HeaderRecord
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Trying to read the values of some properties may cause e crash (e.g. trying to read
        ' the IsValid property of an ASP.NET page before validation has taken place)
        ' Log the error and just return everything we have so far
        Return HeaderRecord
    End Try
End Function
```